# How can do restful api change password in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, restful-authentication, change-password

How can I do change Password Functionality using Restful API in Codeigniter.

I tried A code But It is Not Working and not catching in postman.

This is my controller Part:-

```
 public function change_post()
{
    try
        {   
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            if ($id != '')
            {
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldPassword','Old Password','required|max_length[20]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPassword','New Password','required|max_length[20]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cNewPassword','Confirm new Password','required|matches[newPassword]|max_length[20]');

                if($this->form_validation->run() == BOOL_F)
                {
                    echo validation_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                    $oldPassword = $this->input->post('oldPassword');
                    $newPassword = $this->input->post('newPassword');

                    $resultPas = $this->user_model->matchOldPassword($id, $oldPassword);

                    if($resultPas)
                    {
                        $this->response("password no match.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $changeData = array('password'=>md5($newPassword));

                        $result = $this->user_model->changePassword($id, $changeData);

                        if($result > 0) { $this->response([
                                            'message' => 'password changed successful.',
                                            'data' => $change
                                            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); }
                        else {$this->response("enter password first.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);}

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("The Data Already Register or The Data is Empty");
            }             
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
           $error = array($e->getmessage());
           $errormsg = json_encode($error);
           echo $errormsg;
        }
}
```

This is My Model Part:-

```
function matchOldPassword($id, $oldPassword)
{
    $this->db->select('id, password');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('admins');

    $admin = $query->result();
    if(!empty($admin)){
        if(md5($oldPassword, $admin[0]->password)){
            return $admin;
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

function changePassword($id, $adminData)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('admins', $adminData);

    $this->db->last_query();

    return TRUE;
}
```

But it is not working at all. How can i do correct Method to implement change password using Restful API in Codeigniter

Comment: please someone tell the right code or my mistake

Comment: Tell which rest library you used to generate output $this->response

Comment: explain about REST_Controller

Comment: i am using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the mandatory files from that library to this application

```
application\libraries\REST_Controller.php
application\libraries\Format.php
application\config\rest.php
application\language\english\rest_controller_lang.php
```

**Changes needed**

`$change` was not defined in your code
slight changes did in controller and model

Here the working code.

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
use \Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class Test extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function index_post()
    {
        try{   
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            if ($id != '')
            {
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldPassword','Old Password','required|max_length[20]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPassword','New Password','required|max_length[20]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cNewPassword','Confirm new Password','required|matches[newPassword]|max_length[20]');

                if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
                {
                    echo validation_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                    $oldPassword = $this->input->post('oldPassword');
                    $newPassword = $this->input->post('newPassword');

                    $resultPas = $this->user_model->matchOldPassword($id, $oldPassword);

                    if($resultPas)
                    {

                        $this->set_response("password no match.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $changeData = array('password'=>md5($newPassword));

                        $result = $this->user_model->changePassword($id, $changeData);

                        if($result > 0) { $this->set_response([
                                            'message' => 'password changed successful.',
                                            'data' => $changeData
                                            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); }
                        else { $this->set_response("enter password first.", REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("The Data Already Register or The Data is Empty");
            }             
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
           $error = array($e->getmessage());
           $errormsg = json_encode($error);
           echo $errormsg;
        }
    }


}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function matchOldPassword($id, $oldPassword)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, password');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('admins');
        $admin = $query->result();

        if(!empty($admin) && (md5($oldPassword) == $admin[0]->password) ){
            return false;
        }

        return true;        
    }

    function changePassword($id, $adminData)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('admins', $adminData);

        $this->db->last_query();

        return TRUE;
    }

}
?>
```

**How to access**

```
method - post
url - http://hostname/Test57471803/change
```